# How to know whether I'm running from the GAC or not?

Tags: .net, gac

Given a class library DLL that can be installed on the GAC (production) or not (development), I need to know whether the executing assembly is running from the GAC or not. How can I know this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try checking the [`Assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.globalassemblycache.aspx) property?

```
bool loadedFromGac = this.GetType().Assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache;
```

...or:

```
bool loadedFromGac = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GlobalAssemblyCache;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the AssembyInfo class to find out the loaded assemblies for your app. The returned Assembly objects have a property called GlobalAssemblyCache which indicates what you need.

[MSDN Docs for Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly_members.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason updating the source code to include this isn't an option, try the Fusion Log Viewer (fuslogvw.exe). Included as part of the Visual Studio tools, (open a tools command prompt from the Visual Studio menu group on Windows to have these on your path), the Fusion Log Viewer logs all the assemblies loaded by applications, and where they are loaded from.

It's helped me get to the bottom of quite a few problems related to picking up wrong versions of assemblies, assemblies from unexpected places, etc, over the years. The amount of information provided can be overwhelming, but it provides a definitive answer for your application or anyone else's as to what DLLs are loaded.

Here's the Microsoft documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx